# Dought regarding tomcat bin directory & configuring eclispse for tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, ubuntu-12.10

I had installed tomcat7 in Ubuntu 12.10 by 
**`sudo apt-get install tomcat7`**
I have two problems..
First one is, When go to the tomcat installation directory i.e **/etc/tomcat** directory, i didn't find **bin** directory. Where it is?
Second one is, While configuring Eclipse IDE for Tomcat7 i followed these steps
1) gone to the **Preferences**
2) On servers tab i choose **Runtime Environment**
3) Clicked on **add** button, i had chosen  **apache** and then chosen **Apache Tomcatv7.0** then i have Clicked next.
4) There i have given Tomcat installation directory as **`/etc/tomcat7`** then i got error like following:
**Unknown version of Tomcat was specified.**
So, please help me to fix these problems......

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and the only mistake was to select /usr/share/tomcat7 folder instead of /etc/tomcat7 folder because bin exists in /usr/share/tomcat7 folder.

Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 1):

I guess English is not your first language, its doubt and not dought :-)

In Ubuntu you have to provide the location /usr/share/tomcat7 in Eclipse for it to work. Other way to find which directory is to run the following code

```
locate bin | grep tomcat7
```

and find where tomcat7 installation directory is.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: command `locate` not found

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a "which tomcat" and make sure you're looking for the bin directory in the proper location. If you didn't get a bin directory then you either aren't looking in the right place or your installation process had some serious problems. Try looking too at your environment variables (CATALINA_HOME).

In Eclipse, I believe you are failing because it isn't getting the bin directory. Once you get past your first question, it should certainly help you to answer the second.

Hope that helps.